# Why does NAudio only grab one channel with my "What you Hear" volume control?

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm attempting to add a volume control slider for the audio device I have selected. Most of the time this works properly, but for some reason when I use this method, my volume control slider only affects the left channel. The volume on the right channel is still 100% (where I last left it via windows).

I thought this may be because I was grabbing FirstOrDefault() so I tried grabbing a list instead, which still only results in 1 item. I must be missing something.

This is the code that gets the UnsignedMixerControl:

```
    private List<UnsignedMixerControl> _mixerControls;
    public List<UnsignedMixerControl> TryGetVolumeControls()
    {
        return _mixerControls 
            ?? (_mixerControls = waveIn.GetMixerLine().Controls.Where(c => c.ControlType == MixerControlType.Volume)
                                    .Select(c=>c as UnsignedMixerControl).ToList());
    }
```

Thank you for any ideas you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixer controls can be multi-channel, and the Value setter in NAudio does attempt to set the same value on each channel. If you are able to debug against the NAudio source code you might be able to find out if this is a stereo control and whether the value is being set for each channel correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the information, Mark. I haven't yet had time to download and debug against the NAudio source code, but I'll update the question with my findings once I do.